# Objective C Deamon not start

Tags: objective-c, macos, service

i have developed a Deamon that run at start of Mac, this deamon run correctly until i have install a new OSX 10.8.5 [this deamon run correctly for 10.8.4].

i don't know where is my error,

i have create a Terminal app that write a dictionary like this:

```
KeepAlive = 1;
Label = "vetrya.ControlloPresenza";
MachServices =     {
    "vetrya.ControlloPresenza" = 1;
};
Program = "/System/Library/VetryaControllo/ControlloPresenza";
ProgramArguments = start;
RunAtLoad = 1;
StartInterval = 20;
inetdCompatibility =     {
    Wait = 0;
};
```

an then write this dict inside this Dir: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/

but now this precess not start, anyone know the reason of this?

this how i write dict of and the result of plist war write correctly

```
NSMutableArray* arrayArguments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
[arrayArguments addObject:@"/System/Library/VetryaControllo/ControlloPresenza"];
[arrayArguments addObject:@"start"];
NSDictionary* dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"Wait", nil];
NSDictionary* dictNew = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"vetrya.ControlloPresenza", nil];

[self.controlloPresenza setObject:@"vetrya.ControlloPresenza" forKey:@"Label"];
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:@"/System/Library/VetryaControllo/ControlloPresenza" forKey:@"Program"];
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:@"start" forKey:@"ProgramArguments"]; 
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:dict forKey:@"inetdCompatibility"];
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:dictNew forKey:@"MachServices"];
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"KeepAlive"];
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"RunAtLoad"];
[self.controlloPresenza setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20] forKey:@"StartInterval"];
```

i have make some change now the plist is follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>vetrya.ControlloPresenza</string>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>vetrya.ControlloPresenza</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/System/Library/VetryaControllo/ControlloPresenza</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <string>start</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

i have found on line that to register the Daemon to next reboot i can use this Terminal comand:

```
sudo chown root:wheel <name.plist>
sudo chmod 644 <name.plist>
```

but when i create the NSTask like this:

```
 NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:_registrationPath];
    [task setArguments: @[@"sudo", @"chown",@"root:wheel",@"vetrya.ControlloPresenza.plist"]];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:_registrationPath];
    [task setArguments: @[@"sudo", @"chmod",@"644",@"vetrya.ControlloPresenza.plist"]];

    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
```

but at the end i have this error: failed: 22, "Invalid argument".
how i have to write this comand?

Regards

Comment: Are there any error messages in `Console.app` to give you a clue why it's not working?

Comment: Nothing happens, the process not start and the deamon not start.... like if this plist not exist inside system dir...

Comment: And you are getting no logs at all ? (`/var/log/system.log`).  I find that surprising; OSX is very "chatty".

Comment: Nothing about the Deamon at startup...

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the `inetdCompatibility` options when you are not listening on a socket?  Do you want your daemon to stay up all the time? (if so you will need `<keepAlive></true>`).  You show errors with `launchctl` (below) - you must get that working *before* you can expect the system to run your daemon automatically.

Comment: with launchclt they said that: "launchctl: Dubious ownership on file (skipping): /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/vetrya.ControlloPresenza.plist
nothing found to load"

Comment: That's another issue then; however you have not explained your use of `inetdCompatibility`.

Comment: i have insert 'inetdCompatibility' because this Deamon run a terminal app to execute an http get to a local server but was only a test... then i remove it now... and nothing change

Comment: i have found some solution but now i have just another problem... can read new problem in starting post...

Comment: Why are you using `NSTask` to do things there are system calls for?

Comment: i don't know another way to execute this comand... i use this comand for regiter the daemond's plist to boot...

Comment: So you don't know that there's a `chown()` and `chmod()` system call that would do this quicker, more efficiently and with less code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you've just omitted this from the sample you've shown in the question because you say you're writing out the values, but if you read the Apple documentation on [Daemons and Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), you'll see that the plist requires you to specify keys and values, like this: -

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>Label</key>
<string>"vetrya.ControlloPresenza"</string>
```

Additionally, if that's what you are doing, I see that you have *program arguments* set to a value, rather than an array of strings, which would make it:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
```

Comment: no because you see a stamp of Dictionary, when you write a plist from dict i was write correctly...

Comment: Can you post the output of the plist that is written by your code?

Comment: i have modify the original post with plist

Comment: In your first comment you wrote "you see a stamp of Dictionary"; I don't understand what you mean by that, can you please explain?

Comment: i have create a "terminal program" that create a plist end insert it on the currect dir, inside the code of the program i create a dict call "controlloPresenza" [can show this dict inside my post]. then i write the dict in the currect directory. when i said that you can see the stamp of dict i'was talkin about NSlog(@"%@",self.controlloPresenza).

Comment: Have you tried manually launching the daemon with launctl load? Does that work?

Comment: not work... now is invalid argument if i write
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/vetrya.ControlloPresenza.plist

Comment: What are the permissions on the daemon and who is it owned by?